# AD B2C direct sign-in shows {OIDC:LoginHint} rather than email address

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to use direct sign-in in the SelfAsserted-EmailCollect TechnicalProfile. I've set the default value on the InputClaim to {OIDC:LoginHint} and passed a login_hint query parameter, but in the login UI I see {OIDC:LoginHint} rather than the email address I passed in the query parameter.

Here is my claims provider:

```
<ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>SelfAsserted</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-EmailCollect">
          <DisplayName>Email</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted.profileupdate</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" DefaultValue="{OIDC:LoginHint}"/>          
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
          </OutputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
  </ClaimsProviders>
```

I'm using this url to login:

```
https://mytenant.b2clogin.com/cubiksconnectv2.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1A_Signup_Signin_Dev&client_id=myclientId&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44381%2Fsignin-oidc&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login&login_hint=test@address.com
```

This is what the [Login UI](https://pasteboard.co/ItTggiR.png) looks like.

Comment: Hi @Code Monkey. I believe this is occurring because `{OIDC:LoginHint}` is only supported for the unified (sign up and sign in) page. I'll check for a possible workaround...

Comment: Oh thats why it didn't work? Interested in a workaround :)

Comment: @ChrisPadgett - Thanks for commenting. Any pointers towards a workaround would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there a way to do this without JavaScript? Is that technically possible to create a technicalprofile to pre-populate the email claim from {OIDC:LoginHint}? Or, to use an inputtrasnformation to pre-populate the email claim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to add JavaScript to the login page to fill the e-mail field from the `login_hint` query parameter.

```js
var _findSearchParameter = function (name) {
  var matches = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)')
    .exec(window.location.search);

  return (matches !== null) ? matches[1] || 0 : false;
};

var loginHintValue = _findSearchParameter('login_hint');

if (loginHintValue) {
  $('#email').val(loginHintValue);
}
```

Comment: This works really well - Thanks @ChrisPadgett! I had to switch to using b2clogin.com and add a ScriptExecution element as per this document to get it working. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-samples

Comment: Is this solution still the best possible solution? I recently updated my TrustFrameworkBase.xml for Azure B2C and noticed that {OIDC:LoginHint} was being used in SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email, but documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview suggests IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling and AlwaysUseDefaultValue should be used to make it stick, for which the default TrustFrameworkBase.xml does not do. And this may explain why it does not work.

Comment: @Reuben No. I would not consider the best solution anymore. And yes, what you just said is true. Both values need to be included in the technical profile for "{OIDC:LoginHint}" to work according to Microsoft documentation and my own experience. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview under 'Using claim resolvers' section for 'self-asserted' technical profiles.

Answer (score 0):

The above solution worked well for me after enabling Javascript as per documentation.

I added the following script to the bottom of the page:

```
<script data-preload="false">
    $(function () {
        var loginHint = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get("login_hint");
        $("#email").val(loginHint);
    });
</script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To use a claim resolver in a technical profile, you should set the `IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling` metadata key to `true`.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview#using-claim-resolvers

Answer (score 0):

You will need to enable one metadata setting and also specify to always use the default value as per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview#using-claim-resolvers):

```xml
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>SelfAsserted</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-EmailCollect">
      <DisplayName>Email</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted.profileupdate</Item>
        <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" DefaultValue="{OIDC:LoginHint}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />          
      </InputClaims>
      <DisplayClaims>
        <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" Required="true" />
      </DisplayClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
      </OutputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

Without AlwaysUseDefaultValue the resolver did not work.
Adding in both the metadata setting to enable resolvers and setting it to always use default value made the login_hint work.