# B2C Sign-up screen shows {OIDC:LoginHint} instead of the login

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, aad-b2c

I am passing an email of a prospective member in the login_hint from my website to B2C. In my custom policy I am setting the email claim of the "SignUp" TechnicalProfile to {OIDC:LoginHint}

```
           <TechnicalProfile Id="CustomLocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail">
                <DisplayName>Email signup</DisplayName>
                <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
                <Metadata>
                    <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
                    <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignup</Item>
                </Metadata>
                <CryptographicKeys>
                    <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
                </CryptographicKeys>
                <InputClaims>
                    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" DefaultValue="{OIDC:LoginHint}" />
                </InputClaims>
                <OutputClaims>
```

But instead of seeing the user's email, the string {OIDC:LoginHint} is displayed in the form:

[image]

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57613091/ad-b2c-direct-sign-in-shows-oidcloginhint-rather-than-email-address) from 2018 with a suggested workaround of using JavaScript to populate the email field on the Sign Up form. But, I don't use custom templates, so the JavaScript workaround won't work for me.

All I need is to populate the email claim with the value passed in {OIDC:LoginHint}. Is there any way to solve this in the policy XML?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a selfAsserted technical profile, you must:

- The IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling metadata must be set to true.
- The input or output claims attribute AlwaysUseDefaultValue must be set to true.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview#using-claim-resolvers

An example of using both settings is here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview#restful-technical-profile

Comment: I am using a custom displaycontrol to verify the email using a custom mail server, and it seems to be blanking the value set by my inputclaim as you directed. Any Ideas?

Comment: turns out i needed to add the inputClaim for my email in the Display Control